Persist app state across reinstalls/multiple devices
So I’m trying to setup an existing app to work with iCloud syncing. The syncing part seems to be working for the most part.
When the app is first installed it sets up some data locally.
Throughout the life of the app additional data is added through updates. There is a user default setup that stores the current data version, then compares it with the new version. If it’s newer, then loads the additional data.
The issue I’ve got is a user can delete the app and reinstall, or install on another device which has that data version as 0, prompting another import even though the data in the cloud is current version, resulting in duplicate data once the sync is done.
How can I persist that version data? I’ve seen NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore which seems to be a cloud based version of user defaults, but it says not to rely on it if it’s critical to app functions
